# How to extract custom Principal in OAuth2 Resource Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using **Keycloak** as my OAuth2 Authorization Server and I configured an OAuth2 Resource Server for Multitenancy following this official example on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-multitenancy).
The current Tenant is resolved considering the *Issuer* field of the **JWT** token.
Hence the token is verified against the **JWKS** exposed at the corresponding **OpenID Connect** well known endpoint.

This is my Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class OrganizationSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TenantService tenantService;
    private List<Tenant> tenants;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.tenants = this.tenantService.findAllWithRelationships();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .authenticationManagerResolver(new MultiTenantAuthenticationManagerResolver(this.tenants));
    }
}
```

and this is my custom **AuthenticationManagerResolver**:

```
public class MultiTenantAuthenticationManagerResolver implements AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> {

    private final AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> resolver;

    private List<Tenant> tenants;

    public MultiTenantAuthenticationManagerResolver(List<Tenant> tenants) {
        this.tenants = tenants;

        List<String> trustedIssuers = this.tenants.stream()
                .map(Tenant::getIssuers)
                .flatMap(urls -> urls.stream().map(URL::toString))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        this.resolver = new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(trustedIssuers);
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager resolve(HttpServletRequest context) {
        return this.resolver.resolve(context);
    }
}
```

Now, because of the design of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver.TrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver`
which is **private**, the only way I can think in order to extract a custom principal is to reimplement everything that follows:

- **TrustedIssuerJwtAuthenticationManagerResolver**
- the returned **AuthenticationManager**
- the **AuthenticationConverter**
- the **CustomAuthenticationToken** which extends **JwtAuthenticationToken**
- the **CustomPrincipal**

To me it seems a lot of *Reinventing the wheel*, where my only need would be to have a custom Principal.

The examples that I found don't seem to suit my case since they refer to OAuth2Client or are not tought for Multitenancy.

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor
- [How to extend OAuth2 principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708406/how-to-extend-oauth2-principal)

Do I really need to reimplement all such classes/interfaes or is there a smarter approach?

Comment: did you find any other information on this matter?

Comment: Sadly still nothing

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? Could you give more information?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, without reimplementing a huge amount of classes. This is without using a JwtAuthenticationToken however.

```java
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
      ...
      .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver()));
  }

  @Bean
  JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver() {

    List<String> issuers = ... // get this from list of tennants or config, whatever
    Predicate<String> trustedIssuer = issuers::contains;
    Map<String, AuthenticationManager> authenticationManagers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    AuthenticationManagerResolver<String> resolver = (String issuer) -> {
      if (trustedIssuer.test(issuer)) {
        return authenticationManagers.computeIfAbsent(issuer, k -> {
          var jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer);
          var provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder);
          provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationService::loadUserByJwt);
          return provider::authenticate;
        });
      }
      return null;
    };
    
    return new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(resolver);
  }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class JwtAuthenticationService {

  public AbstractAuthenticationToken loadUserByJwt(Jwt jwt) {
    
    UserDetails userDetails = ... // or your choice of principal
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = ... // extract from jwt or db
    ...
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, authorities);
  }
}
```